# how to get the final results in nodejs mysql mutli sql query

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

how i can get the final results gracefully except using asyncjs.

current code is not graceful, any othe method ?

thanks a lot.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    connection.query('select * from ued_task where taskState=0 and isQ=0 order by taskId desc', function(err, tasks, fields) {
        tasks.forEach(function(task, index){
            task.userIds = (task['UD']+task['UI']+task['builder']).replace(/\,+/g,',').replace(/\,$/, '').split(',');
            task.users = [];
            task.userIds.forEach(function(single) {
                connection.query("select * from user where userId=" + single, function(err, rows, fields) {
                    task.users.push({
                        'name' : rows[0].name,
                        'ename' : rows[0].userName,
                        'position' : rows[0].position
                    });
                    if(index === tasks.length-1){
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log(tasks);
                        res.render('index', { 
                            title: 'task sys',
                            tasks: tasks,
                            moment: moment
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

    var result = {};
    result.title = 'task sys';
    result.moment = moment;

    var f3 = function(single){

        connection.query("select * from user where userId=" + single, function(err, rows, fields) {
            task.users.push({
                'name' : rows[0].name,
                'ename' : rows[0].userName,
                'position' : rows[0].position
            });
            if(index === tasks.length-1){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(tasks);
                res.render('index', result);
            }
        });

    }

    var f2 = function(task, index){
        task.userIds = (task['UD']+task['UI']+task['builder']).replace(/\,+/g,',').replace(/\,$/, '').split(',');
        task.users = [];
        task.userIds.forEach(f3);
    }

    var f1 = function(cb){
        var sql = 'select * from ued_task where taskState=0 and isQ=0 order by taskId desc'
        connection.query(sql, function(err, tasks, fields) {
            result.tasks = tasks;
            tasks.forEach(f2);
        }); 
    };

    f1();

};
```

i have been edited

Comment: My description is wrong , not last results, it's final results, like my new update code, thanks.